# High concurrency upserts cause deadlocks and query time of > 30s

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm working on an application which uses EF6 for most database operations, and for the most part the database stuff is non-critical and isn't under a lot of load. There is one exception to this rule, where we have a stream of possibly 100/s events coming in which need to insert or update a row in a specific table based on a column value.

I'm a little weak with SQL in general, but I've written this query to insert or update and return the id of the element:

```
DECLARE @Id [int];

MERGE {tableName} WITH (UPDLOCK) AS target
USING (SELECT @MatchName AS id) AS source
ON source.id = target.MatchColumn
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET @Id = target.Id, ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (...) VALUES (...);

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @Id = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as [int]);
END;
SELECT @Id;
```

It's done inside of an (EF) serializable transaction block and it's the only thing that executes in an explicit transaction, and is the only code that *updates* this table. (other things can read). If a transaction is rolled back by the database (EF throws an exception) it is retried immediately up to 3 times.

The problem is that when we start getting into higher load situations we can end up in this state where so many things are trying to update the database and queries against this table can start to take 30+ seconds (queries to other tables remain fine). I'm under the impression that even though this executes in a serializable transaction it will only lock rows that are selected by the merging matching expression, and this should be a relatively quick operation.

I've been doing some research the past days and some people suggest that only a `HOLDLOCK` is sufficient in the default transaction, and others claim that a serializable transaction is necessary or you could have data integrity problems.

I was hoping someone could explain why the long deadlocks might be happening, and in detail what locking mechanism is optimal in this scenario.

Comment: Would be good if you execute this statement with some values and attach actual execution plan to the question.

Comment: @Evk: The values are just a few integer/ short string columns, could attach execution plan in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `merge` acquires `updlocks`, so `with (updlock)` is not doing  anything for you. Changing your `updlock` to `holdlock` (or `serializable`) and running the statement in a transaction will guarantee that the proper locks are acquired and held for the duration of the operation.

> To prevent concurrent sessions from inserting data with the same key, an incompatible lock must be acquired to ensure only one session can read the key and that lock must be held until the transaction completes.

- [UPSERT Race Condition With `Merge` - Dan Guzman](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

---

Do you need to use `set transaction isolation level serializable`?

In this instance I don't think there would be any difference by explicitly setting the transaction isolation level to `serializable` if the above code is all that would be in the transaction. `merge with (holdlock)` is going to acquire update locks by default, which are not compatible with shared locks, using the `holdlock` hint solves the race-condition issue as explained by Dan Guzman in the referenced article and excerpt above.

---

`with (holdlock)` is a [table hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). Table hints override the default behavior of the statement.

If there were other statements in your transaction, then those would be effected by the difference in transaction isolation level from the default isolation level or an explicitly set `set transaction isolation level` (which is session level) unless overridden with a table hint.

Highest granularity wins in:

- lowest: Database (default is `read committed`)
- middle: Session (`set transaction isolation level ...`)
- highest: Table Hint (`with (updlock, serializable)`)

More on Transaction Isolation Levels:

- [SQL Server Isolation Levels: A Series - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels)
- [Questions About T-SQL Transaction Isolation Levels You Were Too Shy to Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: So what would the table behavioural difference be between a serializable transaction without `holdlock` and say, a repeatable-read transaction with `holdlock`?

Comment: @caesay both of those scenarios = serializable.

Comment: I've decreased the level of concurrency by scaling back our production servers. I've also switched to a repeatable-read transaction with a `holdlock`. I have not noticed any locking quite so bad, but definitely seen inserts take > 3s so it's still not ideal.

Comment: @caesay can you post the complete code for the transaction?